# Cannot connect to MongoDB (run in another docker-compose) inside a Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I run MongoDB using this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  logging-database:
    image: mongo:5.0.6
    container_name: "mongo-logging-db"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: users
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - /somewhere/on/my/machine:/data/db
```

I can access the MongoDB from the host machine as normal using `mongosh`:

```
mongosh  --host my_host_ip --port 27018 --username admin
```

However, I cannot access this MongoDB from inside *another* Docker container (different docker-compose file, and notice that I don't use `host` as a network mode). It only returns a time-out error:

```
my_host_ip:27018: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6468621731162cc098a3fb08, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('my_host_ip', 27018) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('my_host_ip:27018: timed out')
```

The `mongo_uri` from inside the container I used to connect is:

```
mongodb://admin:admin@my_host_ip:27018
```

This happens only for MongoDB service. I can `curl` or `ping` to another service normally (in a different docker-compose file, different port, within the same host machine).

Comment: I think you need to define both containers in the same docker-compose file because if you using different docker-compose yml file for creating the containers then docker will create a different network for each yml file so that's why it is not able to find out your mongo db because it does not present on same network. Hope it helps you.

Comment: As you see, I tried to connect via the host IP. This is the reason that I exposed the port 27017 to the host network (via port 27018) and connect to DB with `my_host_ip:27018`.